# How to pass the pointer of a struct and get the values ​of the variables of that struct in lua

Tags: c, lua

I have a code where it works, but it doesn't work the way I want

I'm trying to use the struct pointer and access the variables from within the struct in lua

I have the following c code which is the lua function

```c
int GetStruct(lua_State *ls) {
    lua_Integer id = (int)luaL_checkinteger(ls, 1);

    struct member *mb = get_member(id); 

    if (mb == NULL)
        return 0;

    lua_newtable(ls);

    lua_pushlightuserdata(ls, mb);
    lua_setfield(ls, -2, "mb");

    lua_pushinteger(ls, mb->mid);
    lua_setfield(ls, -2, "mid");

    lua_pushinteger(ls, mb->mpos);
    lua_setfield(ls, -2, "mpos");
    
    lua_pushinteger(ls, mb->mtime);
    lua_setfield(ls, -2, "mtime");

    return 1;
}
```

Now inside the lua I can use it as follows

```lua
local mystruct = GetStruct(id);

print(mystruct.mb)
print(mystruct.mid)
```

That way I always have to use mystruct.mb to get the pointer

I want to change this, whenever I assign the GetStruct function to a local var of lua, the pointer must be returned

And whenever you use this `local var` like for example `var.mid` or `var.mpos`

Example of how I want to use

```lua
local mystruct = GetStruct(id); -- in this case GetStruct returns the mb pointer
    
print(mystruct.mid)
print(mystruct.mpos)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: the "how I can use" and the "how I want to use" are exactly the same?

Comment: @user253751 It's not the same, you didn't read it, I want that when using `local mystruct = GetStruct(id);` the **mb** pointer is returned and if using `mystruct.mid` the **id** is returned

It has a small difference from the current code

Comment: what's the difference? mystruct.mid already returns the id and mystruct.mpos already returns the pos; this is not new

Comment: So, you want the lightuserdata (you incorrectly call it "mb pointer") to be indexable?  It is impossible.  You need a full userdata with "__index" function in its metatable to be able to index it in Lua.

Comment: On the second thought, you may define a metatable for lightuserdata (it will be shared between all lightuserdatum in this Lua VM), so all lightuserdatum will be indexable.

Comment: But using a Lua table (as you are currently doing) is the simplest solution.  BTW, what's wrong with this solution?  Why you think lightuserdata is better?

Comment: @ESkri It's a matter of taste how I like to write code

How can I use userdata then, could you give me an example?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html) is for Lua 5.1, so some small details may differ from Lua 5.4

Comment: For a concrete answer, you will need to update the question with a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post a more complete example, including the details of `get_member` (what is a `struct member` / how are they created, stored, and destroyed?). As pointed out, this could be done with full userdata, which gives better support for metatable usage. In this case the memory is managed by Lua, and finalizers (`__gc` metamethod) would be used to clean up your external collection(s).